# Use functions to dll in php on windows

Tags: php, dll, com

I need to use the functions of a dll using php. I have read that through the COM class I can call their methods and access their properties in php. This is my code for test:

```
 <?php
        $obj = new COM("myfile.dll");
        $output = $obj->Initial(); // Call the "Initial" method in the dll
```

But show this error:

```
error: Failed to create COM object `CyTconnect': Sintaxis no v�lida
```

I use windows, Apache, Php 7.1.12, activate the php `com_dotnet` extension, and register the dll with `REGSVR32`. Any suggestion?

Comment: Thanks for your response, I read the documentation but this not help, somewhere other suggestion?